# Convert mysql query with date_format in doctrine dql

Tags: doctrine-orm, dql

How can I convert this query in doctrine?

```
select distinct date_format(data_fine, '%d/%m/%Y')
from calendario
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

> - Use Doctrine’s NativeSQL functions to write an SQL statement
> - Write a User-Defined Function so that Doctrine recognises DATE_FORMAT when written in DQL and can successfully transform it into
>     SQL.

From http://www.uvd.co.uk/blog/labs/using-mysqls-date_format-in-doctrine-2-0/

Answer (score -2):

You need define a name for this row:

```
select distinct date_format(data_fine, '%d/%m/%Y') AS <name> from calendario
```

Example:

```
select distinct date_format(data_fine, '%d/%m/%Y') AS day from calendario
```